# Recursive umount after rbind mount

Tags: mount, unmounting

When entering a chroot is sometimes necessary to mount /sys and /dev using -rbind instead of -bind in order to insure everything is in it's right place when somebody goes looking.

The problem comes when unmounting.

A simple umount always fails; with the children being mounted as well it appears to be in use:

```
$ umount /mnt/chroot/sys
umount: /mnt/chroot/sys: device is busy.
    (In some cases useful info about processes that use
     the device is found by lsof(8) or fuser(1))
```

Another possible solution is to list the mounts from proc, and umount each of those like so:

```
$ grep /mnt/chroot/sys /proc/mounts | cut -f2 -d" " | sort -r | xargs umount
```

However this fails as well because the recursive mounts are not actually registered in the mtab:

```
/mnt/chroot/sys/kernel/security is not mounted (according to mtab)
```

Perhaps the solution is to perform a lazy umount, but this seems pretty dangerous to me.

Is there a better way to do this that I've missed?

Comment: Are you sure that `/mnt/chroot/sys/kernel/security` is mounted at that point? What is the output of `grep /sys/kernel/security /proc/mounts`? `umount` doesn't need its argument to be listed in `/etc/mtab`. If you pass it `-n`, it won't open the file at all.

Comment: If you look closely at my grep command for creating the xargs for umount, I'm only sending it the mounts listed in /proc/mounts

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The credit goes to [Gilles](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/885/gilles%20%22Gilles%27) for this answer; Gilles noted in the question comments that the '-n' switch ignores the mtab and unmounts anything listed in /proc/mounts.

From the manpage:

```
-n     Unmount without writing in /etc/mtab.
```

So to answer my question of how to unravel a --rbind mount, this is the full command that worked for me:

```
grep /mnt/chroot/sys /proc/mounts | cut -f2 -d" " | sort -r | xargs umount -n
```

Merci, Gilles!

Comment: Trying `mount --rbind / /mnt && umount -n /mnt/dev/shm` (or pts), I get `umount: /mnt/dev/shm: target is busy`.  `umount -l /mnt` kills the system (e.g. sudo fails saying stdin isn't a tty).  This is on an installed Fedora system.  I guess it's an old problem of mine: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269695/mounting-new-filesystem-affects-non-recursive-bind-mounts

Answer (score 24):

This worked for me correctly -- https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/264488/4319:

```
mount --rbind /dev /mnt/test
mount --make-rslave /mnt/test
umount -R /mnt/test
```

It was important to have the two first commands as two separate commands: do not combine `--rbind` and `--make-rslave` in one invocation of mount.

Without `--make-rslave`, the behavior was unwanted (and not successful):

- `umount -l` would affect the original old mountpoints, too,
- and `umount -R` would be affected by the busy (open) files under the original old mountpoints. (Very unexpected...)

Comment: Don't know if this has been fixed in a recent version of mount, but it's perfectly ok to combine `--rbind` and `--make-rslave` in the same mount invocation: `mount --rbind --make-rslave /dev /mnt/test`

Comment: While you can combine the two arguments, it makes it do a non-recursive mount instead.  So it doesn't actually work as intended.

Comment: Tested on Ubuntu 20.04; works a treat.  My understanding from the manpage is that combining `--rbind` and `--make-rslave` is possible, although experimental and non-atomic (so equivalent to the multiple invokations).  In my testing, combining the options on a single command worked as expected.

Answer (score 7):

Since [util-linux v2.23](https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/v2.23/v2.23-ReleaseNotes) (25-Apr-2013) the `umount` command supports the `-R, --recursive` option.

Here is what the man page says:

> Recursively unmount each specified directory.  Recursion for each directory will stop if any unmount operation in the chain fails for any reason.  The relationship between mountpoints is determined by  `/proc/self/mountinfo`  entries.   The  filesystem must be specified by mountpoint path; a recursive unmount by device name (or UUID) is unsupported.

For filesystems mounted with `--rbind` it might be needed to run `mount --make-rslave` before trying to unmount them if `umount` complains about `device is busy`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for that. I use this in my scripts to unmount the entire chroot-tree:
(Make sure to set $MNT accordingly)

```
for dir in $(grep "$MNT" /proc/mounts | cut -f2 -d" " | sort -r)
do
    umount $dir 2> /dev/null
    (( $? )) && umount -n $dir
done
```