# Unmount a rbind mount without affecting the original mount

Tags: linux, mount, linux-kernel, unmounting, bind-mount

*Asked on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/757599/unmount-a-rbind-mount-without-affecting-the-original-mount) but didn't get enough attention, so reposted here, with the hope some people here know the answer.*

There is another [question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120827/recursive-umount-after-rbind-mount) discussing about umounting rbind mounts, but the solution has unwanted effect.  Consider the following directory layout:

```
.
├── A_dir
│   └── mount_b
├── B_dir
│   └── mount_c
└── C_dir
```

Now I bind `C_dir` to `B_dir/mount_c` and rbind `B_dir` to `A_dir/mount_b`:

```
[hidden]$ sudo mount --bind C_dir B_dir/mount_c
[hidden]$ sudo mount --rbind B_dir A_dir/mount_b
[hidden]$ mount | grep _dir | wc -l
3
```

Now `umount A_dir/mount_b` will fail, which is not surprising.  According to the answers everywhere on the web, we need to `umount A_dir/mount_b/mount_c` first then `umount A_dir/mount_b`. However, `umount A_dir/mount_b/mount_c` will also unmount `B_dir/mount_c`, which is unwanted:

```
[hidden]$ sudo umount A_dir/mount_b/mount_c
[hidden]$ mount | grep _dir | wc -l
1
```

Now my question is, how do I unmount `A_dir/mount_b` but leaving `B_dir` unaffected, i.e. there is still a bind `B_dir/mount_c` to `C_dir`?

EDIT: this problem doesn't seem to appear in Ubuntu. More specifically, it works fine on my Ubuntu 14.04 but not working on Fedora 23 and CentOS 7. Why there is the difference and what's the work around for Fedora and CentOS?

EDIT: some more information on the actual problem that I am trying to solve.  I tried to create a sandbox and used `--rbind` to mount the `/dev` and `/proc` to the sandbox.  When destroying the sandbox, it seems I can't cleanly destroy it because unmounting `<sandbox-root>/dev/pts` in FC23 and CentOS7 will unmount `/dev/pts`, after which my shell and SSH connections hang and I have to reboot the machine. That's why I am asking if there is a way to unmount the --rbind mounts without affecting submounts.

Comment: This issue has been also brought up at https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/util-linux/+bug/759394

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I found the solution myself.  I simply just need to use `--make-rslave` to make any changes in `A_dir/mount_b` not propagate back to `B_dir`:

```
sudo mount --make-rslave A_dir/mount_b
sudo umount -R A_dir/mount_b
```

See [mount](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man8/mount.8.html) man page section *The shared subtree operations*.

Comment: In some systems, one can even combine `mount --rbind src target --make-rslave` in one call; some systems used to disallow this for me.