# Mounting new filesystem affects non-recursive bind mounts?

Tags: linux, bind-mount

It hasn't always behaved this way, but nowadays I get this inconsistent behaviour.  Bind mounts don't copy existing mounts (unless you use `--rbind`), but new mounts (and unmounts) get copied automatically.  It seems like a bug.  What causes this?

```
# mount --bind / /mnt/tmp
# mount | grep /mnt
/dev/mapper/fedora-root on /mnt/tmp type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
# mount /var/lib/docker
# mount | grep mnt
/dev/mapper/fedora-root on /mnt/tmp type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
/dev/mapper/fedora-docker on /mnt/tmp/var/lib/docker type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
```

This happens on Fedora Workstation 23.  I believe Debian 8 is also affected.

It doesn't happen if I boot bash with no other processes, i.e. `init=/bin/bash`.  So it doesn't seem to be inherent to the Linux kernel.

---

It's annoying because this used to be the simplest way to move files from the root filesystem into a new mount point.  It would be particularly convenient with SELinux (at least if you use `cp`?), because the files would be labeled automatically, avoiding the need for `restorecon` or the like.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to see that new mounts stop being copied, if you run `mount --make-private` on the mount point.

The difference when running bash as init, is that the *source* filesystem has been mounted as private.[*]  Whereas booting the full system is effectively running `--make-shared`.  You can see the difference by looking at `findmnt -o +PROPAGATION`.

Once the root filesystem is mounted as shared, any filesystem mounted directly under it will inherit the same propagation setting.

The root filesystem is being remounted as shared by `systemd`.  This feature was added to systemd around 2012.  It was discussed on the amazing Arch Linux wiki.

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php?title=Talk:Systemd&oldid=411350#Systemd_defaults_.2F_to_rshared.2C_gotcha

https://github.com/systemd/systemd/commit/b3ac5f8cb98757416d8660023d6564a7c411f0a0

---

While you're reading this, I also recommend learning how to [safely disassemble](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/371208/29483) a recursive bind mount.  Because on shared mounts, mounts *and unmounts* propagate in both directions :-).

---

[*] Booting with `init=/bin/bash`, I saw the filesystems mounted as private.  Even though I was still booting with Fedora's `dracut` initramfs, which runs systemd internally.  I'm not 100% sure what was happening here.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know why it happens, but I found a way to avoid it.  At least for most filesystems, you can mount them a second time instead of using a bind mount.

EDIT: using this feature has some problems of its own.  When you mount the filesystem a second time, any filesystem-specific mount options that you pass are silently ignored.

```
# mount /dev/mapper/fedora-root /mnt/tmp
# mount | grep /mnt/tmp
/dev/mapper/fedora-root on /mnt/tmp type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
# mount /var/lib/docker
# mount | grep /mnt/tmp
/dev/mapper/fedora-root on /mnt/tmp type ext4 (rw,relatime,seclabel,data=ordered)
```