# How to unmount a mountpoint with rbind and rslave?

Tags: mount, unmounting, bind-mount

Trying to use a chrooted system via

```
mount -B stage3 gentoo
mount -t sysfs none gentoo/sys
mount -t proc none gentoo/proc
mount -R /dev gentoo/dev
mount --make-rslave gentoo/dev
unshare --fork chroot gentoo
umount -R gentoo
```

After the last umount, dev, dev/pts, dev/shm, dev/mqueue, dev/hugepages were still mounted under stage3.

I have two questions,

1. Why they were mounted to stage3?
2. How could I unmount those? Every mountpoint is busy.

OS: Ubuntu Xenial. Kernel: 4.13.4, but I have got same issue with kernel like 4.10 and others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Why they were mounted to `stage3`?

   Because you bind-mounted `stage3` onto `gentoo` and `stage3` propagation flag is set to `shared` (verify this with: `findmnt -o PROPAGATION stage3`)
2. How could I unmount those? Every mountpoint is busy.

   You've just spawned a `chroot` on the mounted tree. If you want to unmount the tree while the `chroot` command is running, make the mount namespace private to the `chroot`:

   ```
    unshare --mount --fork chroot gentoo
   ```

Comment: (and the default to shared propagation is probably due to systemd: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269695/mounting-new-filesystem-affects-non-recursive-bind-mounts/276700#276700)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Shared sub-tree is always confusing me. For question 2, I ran umount after exited the chroot jail. `umount -R` unmounted gentoo, sys, proc properly. But dev and its children did not get unmounted due to "busy".

Comment: Sorry last comment was not editable. I mean dev and its children (on stage3) did not get unmounted due to "busy". Let me check the share part since dev on gentoo got unmounted.

Comment: @Magicloud It did not get unmounted with the `--mount` option? Use `lsof` to find out what is using it.

Comment: Oh, --mount works here. And --make-private when binding stage3 to gentoo also works.