# How to unmount a recursive bind mount - safely

Tags: mount, unmounting, bind-mount

*Please take care that you have no unsaved work if you test this*.

I ran this command as an experiment, but how can I undo it without rebooting?

```
# mount --rbind / /mnt
```

## What I have tried

1. ```
   # umount /mnt
   umount: /mnt: target is busy.
   ```
2. ```
   # strace -f -e umount,umount2 umount -R /mnt
   umount2("/mnt/var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs", 0) = 0
   umount2("/mnt/sys/kernel/security", 0)  = 0
   umount2("/mnt/sys/fs/cgroup/unified", 0) = -1 EBUSY (Device or resource busy)
   umount: /mnt/sys/fs/cgroup/unified: target is busy.
   +++ exited with 32 +++
   ```
3. ```
   # umount -l /mnt
   # findmnt
   findmnt: can't read /proc/mounts: No such file or directory
   ```

   (this is the catastrophe I warned you about).

## Environment

Fedora 28.

Answer (score 3):

You need to run `mount --make-rprivate /mnt` before you can safely unmount it.  See the question [Mounting new filesystem affects non-recursive bind mounts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269695/mounting-new-filesystem-affects-non-recursive-bind-mounts/276700#276700)

I thought I had tried this, but something went wrong.  Maybe I had missed the `r` off `--make-rprivate`.