# Why duplicate mount --bind cause empty /dev/pts?

Tags: linux, debian, mount

```
$ ls /dev/pts
0  1  ptmx
$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt
$ ls /dev/pts
0  1  ptmx
$ sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt
$ ls /dev/pts
$
```

I run on Debian 9 with Linux 4.14.13 kernel.

Comment: fwiw **a**) it's a `systemd` thing; until I (or someone else) get all things in order for a proper explanation you can **b**) `mount --rbind /dev /mntpoint` (and maybe add the `-o private` option too).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `/tmp/dev/pts/` is empty after the first mount, because you used `mount --bind`, as opposed to `mount --rbind`.

   `/dev/pts/` is one of a number of other filesystems, which are commonly mounted in sub-directories of `/dev/`.
2. `/dev/pts/` becomes empty after the second mount, because of mount propagation.

   When you add the second bind mount of the `/dev/` filesystem, that bind mount is propagated back to `/dev/`.

   There is one Q & A about this behaviour here: [Mounting new filesystem affects non-recursive bind mounts?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/269695/mounting-new-filesystem-affects-non-recursive-bind-mounts/276700#276700)